# python os.rename can't find a file, even though the code check it exists

Tags: python, file, error-handling, operating-system

I have a strange error:

in the code:

```
if os.path.isfile(df_file):
    os.rename(df_file, df_file + '_backup.parquet')
```

I am getting an error:

> ```
>     os.rename(df_file, df_file + '_backup.parquet')
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/5faf97ca101ae0413c383678186bf601.parquet' ->
>     '/data/5faf97ca101ae0413c383678186bf601.parquet_backup.parquet'
> ```

Even though I checked and the file exist! 
what could be the problem ?
The source file and directory are obviously exist

The code is called within a flask thread.

Comment: cant reproduce . Python version  ?

Comment: python 3.6.2 inside debian (tensorflow) docker.

Comment: What do you get if you run this block separetely?

Answer (score 0):

*'/data/5faf97ca101ae0413c383678186bf601.parquet_backup.parquet'* This is an absolute path, which points to the data directory under the root path. I guess you want to use a relative path,'./data/5faf97ca101ae0413c383678186bf601.parquet_backup.parquet'

Comment: its running inside a docker container. and the /data/ is mapped to the root. anyway - the file DOES exists. so why am I getting this error ?